# How to reset footnote numbering in each page (RichEdit Control dev express document)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

docx file has footnote number like this: page1: 1 , page2: 1,2 , page3: 1,2,3 , ...

Now, When load docx file into RichEdit Control, footnote number be like this: page1: 1 , page2: 2,3 , page3:4,5,6

but I want something like this: page1: 1 , page2: 1,2 , page3: 1,2,3

`var docxFilePath = FileManager.GetFilesPath() + projectId + "\\" + bookId + ".docx";`

`BookRichEditControl.LoadDocument(docxFilePath);`

thanks(sorry for bad english)

Comment: You should be able to toggle the footnote numbering from continuous to non-continuous in the User interface, or via code. Review the documentation here to see: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/401716/controls-and-libraries/rich-text-editor/rich-edit-control-document/footnotes-and-endnotes